# How to make kivy window close automatically after specific amount of time?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to close the kivy window automatically without pressing any button after a specific amount of time.

Code:

```py
class Tester(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hi")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tester().run()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand why you have unchecked my answer since the other answer is equivalent to mine (it is the same solution written differently)

Comment: Sir it didn't work

Comment: mmm, how strange, I have tested it. I find it strange that you mark my question as correct without verifying that it works. (Note that in my code the application will close in 5 seconds)

Comment: I have tried with `App().stop` and the `window.stop` but doesn't work.

Comment: My code uses `self.stop`.

Comment: Doesn't work sorry. I'd like to use `App().get_running_app().stop()`
Which works everywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209975/discussion-between-sriram123-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Well, it still seems strange to me. 1) If a code does not work you should not give it an upvote or mark it as correct. 2) If you do not provide code and the user provides the code (like me) then you must execute it as it is without modifications. Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `App().get_running_app().stop()` with the `Clock` to close the kivy window:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class Tester(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hi")

Clock.schedule_once(App().get_running_app().stop, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tester().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Clock to invoke the stop method of the application:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class Tester(App):
    def build(self):

        Clock.schedule_once(self.stop, 5)

        return Label(text="Hi")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tester().run()
```